# React MUI button not obeying CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm scratching my head pretty hard here. I have a button inside a div:

```
<div className='page'>
    <Button variant="outlined" color='primary' className='download'>Download</Button>
</div>
```

The div 'page' takes up with the entire width & height of the screen. I am wanting to lock the button to the bottom right corner. Naturally my first thought was CSS like this:

```
.download{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

However, this does nothing at all. What confuses me is if I set the height and width of the button, the button shape will change.

I have also tried using [sx](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#the-sx-prop) and the StyledEngineProvider but neither made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, surprised I figured it out.

The default styling from MUI has the position as relative. Using sx if I set the position to absolute, i'm able to place it where I wish.